# If $\sum_n x_n$ converge to $L$, what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$?

Tags: analysis, limits, summation

If $\sum_n x_n$ converge to $L < \infty$, what is $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$? 
This is a question I have been asked, but I cannot answer it. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Hint: What are the limits of the sequences $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ defined by $$y_n=\sum_{k=0}^nx_k\qquad z_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}x_k\ ?$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{ n\to \infty}  x_n=\lim _{ n\to \infty} \left (\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i \right )$$ So what can you say about limit of $x_n$?

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_{n}x^n$ converges to a finite number $L$, then we must have $x_n \to 0$.  Without $x_n \to 0$, the sequence of partial sums cannot converge.

Comment: Could you prove it?

Comment: @J.G see my answer,for proof!

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!

Comment: @J.G You're welcome!